# How to enable GZIP with gSOAP?

Tags: compression, gzip, gsoap

I want to enable GZIP compression on my gSOAP client. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GZIP requires the Zlib library, compile sources with -DWITH_GZIP.
It's in the manual. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Do you mean compiling my client code when you say "compile sources"? I am using GCC or VisualStudio2005 to compile. Can you detail the steps?

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Yes, compiling the client code with the define, which is a couple of files.
see: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html